# Unknown Margin affecting layout

Tags: html, css, layout, margin

Hi I have a website I am trying to tidy up.  I have tried resetting all the margins, paddings, specifying size etc.  All haven't lined up these buttons.

It can be found on this link: http://hpif.propertyinfrance.co.uk/app/index.php?action=details&pid=42052&res=rent

Just under the title you will see a "<back" button this needs to be inline with the larger button like divs below it.  For some reason nothing I do will get it to line up.

Can someone point out where Im going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You forgot to add float left to your back button.
#backbutton {
              width: 50px;
              height: 45px;
              margin: 0px;
              padding: 0px;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: 199;
              float: left;
             }
```

Comment: Did that answer your question?